# Trying to validate response data in karate

Tags: json, karate

Here is my response

```
{
  "result": {
    "metadata": {
      "company_employee": [
        "94acdcbf-9c63-4fb8-939a-748fd0c8474d",
        "c7d67a49-6502-4738-8c2e-3842312524bf",
        "f7843e21-3b74-4935-b941-55756d58570c",
        "5ee8120f-738b-4bf8-b7cc-f96271e876b6",
        "0f6e06b9-1244-416c-a674-9e5081f3137d",
        "805ddabd-a1ca-4296-8804-dd87f3311702",
        "6454f8db-9802-4095-96d9-983029430d87",
        "0733cf86-c42d-4043-a0bf-35c6bacea355"
      ]
    },
    "address": "Dhaka",
    "is_active": true,
    "gender": "male",
    "created": "2021-01-18T10:53:07.898Z",
    "date_of_birth": 0,
    "user_name": "st_jahid4",
    "profile_pic": null,
    "last_name": "Jahid",
    "contact": "",
    "is_public": true,
    "id": "20e776b7-523d-4592-9150-1127f9ac4cf1",
    "first_name": "Md.",
    "updated": "2021-08-12T11:56:22.641Z",
    "email": "canon88803@vss6.com"
  },
  "code": 200,
  "status": "ok"
}
```

Schema:

```
* def refmetadata = {company_employee : '#[] uuid'}

* def refresult = 
"""
{ 
    metadata: '#object refmetadata', 
    address: '#string',
    is_active:'#boolean',
    gender:'#string',
    created:'#string',
    date_of_birth:'##null',
    user_name:'#string',
    profile_pic:'##null',
    last_name:'#string',
    contact:'#string',
    is_public:'#boolean',
    id:'#uuid',
    first_name:'#string',
    updated:'#string',
    email:'#string'
}
"""
* def responseData = 
"""
    {
        result: '#object refresult',
        code: '#number',
        status: '#string'
    }
"""
```

Code for validate:

```
 * string jsonData = response
 * match jsonData  == responseData
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues. Note that your example is too complex, so I'm not going top spend time actually trying to run this. Please spend time reading the docs and examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "result": {
    "metadata": {
      "company_employee": [
        "94acdcbf-9c63-4fb8-939a-748fd0c8474d"
      ]
    },
    "address": "Dhaka",
  },
  "code": 200,
  "status": "ok"
}
"""
* def meta = { company_employee : '#[] #uuid' }
* match response.result.metadata == meta
* def result = 
"""
{ 
  metadata: '#(meta)', 
  address: '#string'
}
"""
* def schema = 
"""
{
  result: '#(result)',
  code: '#number',
  status: '#string'
}
"""
* match response == schema
```